# how to create a custom popup menu with flutter same this with Flutter Code

Tags: flutter, dart

how to create a custom popup menu with flutter same this with Flutter Code:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO4Hu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These packages may solve your problem:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/show_more_text_popup
2. https://pub.dev/packages/quds_popup_menu (allows for buttons within the popup)
3. https://pub.dev/packages/super_tooltip

Comment: thanx bro https://pub.dev/packages/super_tooltip